# Querying not analyzed nested value elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, nosql

I am a newbie to elasticsearch, and having hard time querying a `'not_analyzed'` field within a nested object. This is my mapping (I am talking about the `"subscriptions.entity_type"` field) :

```
{
   "app": {
      "mappings": {
         "user_subscriptions": {
            "properties": {
               "subscriptions": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "entity_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                     },
                     "entity_type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "event_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "test": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And this is an example entry :

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "app",
            "_type": "user_subscriptions",
            "_id": "12",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "test": "DevCommunityBundle:Topic",
               "subscriptions": [
                  {
                     "entity_type": "DevCommunityBundle:Topic",
                     "entity_id": 3,
                     "event_name": "test"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When trying to term query the `"test"` field with an exact value, I get the expected result, however, when I try to term query the `"subscriptions.entity_type"` with the same exact value I get no results.

Comment: Can you also show the query you're sending?